# Sort by left joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `orders` table and `order_histories` table. I need to sort `orders` by `order_histories.created_at` but only those `order_histories` that have `state_to = 'submitted'`.

An `order` has multiple `order_histories` and may have none `submitted`. It may also have multiple `submitted` - in that case I'm interested in the last one (hence `MAX(order_histories.created_at)`).

What I have come up with is below. However, this is not sufficient because `orders` without `submitted` `order_history` are not included.

```
SELECT orders.*, MAX(order_histories.created_at) AS date
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_histories ON order_histories.order_id = orders.id
WHERE order_histories.state_to = 'submitted'
GROUP BY orders.id
ORDER BY date ASC, orders.id DESC
```

How can I make it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criteria on an outer-joined table belongs in the `ON` clause not in the `WHERE`  clause:

```
SELECT orders.*, MAX(order_histories.created_at) AS date
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN order_histories ON  order_histories.order_id = orders.id
                          AND order_histories.state_to = 'submitted'
GROUP BY orders.id
ORDER BY date ASC NULLS LAST, orders.id DESC;
```

Using a `WHERE` clause instead rendered your join a mere inner join, because it dismissed all outer-joined rows (i.e. those without a submitted order history record).

Answer (score 2):

In this way, you'll get all orders

- If exists one order with state submitted it returns its date
- If you have more order_histories with state submitted it returns only the max date
- If you have an order without submitted state you'll have NULL in that date (the spirit of LEFT OUTER JOIN)
- If you want to discard orders without state submitted specify it so I'll change the query

Try this:

```
SELECT orders.*, 
(SELECT MAX(oh.created_at) 
FROM order_histories oh
WHERE oh.order_id = orders.id
AND oh.state_to = 'submitted') AS date
FROM orders
ORDER BY date ASC, orders.id DESC
```

Comment: Yes it's often a good idea to aggregate inside a subquery - be it in the `SELECT` clause as shown here or in the `FROM` clause - because the relation to the query is very clear. We want to select each order's latest history date, and this is exactly what this query represents.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner:Thank you dear. Your solution is good too. Important your LEFT JOIN clause movement from WHERE (+1 for you)